# Ember Data Adaptor throws has no method 'updateRecord' even though updateRecord function is implemented?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am rolling my own adaptor for Ember data. Long story short, when I call App.store.updateRecord(App.Model, id ) I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object <DS.Store:ember195> has no method 'updateRecord'`

even though updateRecord function is implemented.

Sample code below ( note for clarity sake, I had all the functions log parameters to console instead of doing what they are suppose to do )

```
// declare application namespace
App = Ember.Application.create();

// instantiate store
App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 2,
    adapter: DS.LocalStorageAdapter.create(),
});

// implement adapter
DS.LocalStorageAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend({

  createRecord: function(store, type, model) {
    console.log('createRecord: ', type, model);

  },


  updateRecord: function(store, type, model) {
    console.log('updateRecord: ', type, model);

  },

  find: function(store, type, id) {
    console.log('find: ', type, id);

  },

  localStorage: {
    set: function( ModelTyp, value ){},

    get: function( ModelType ){},
  }

});

// create model
App.StyleData = DS.Model.extend({

    css_name: DS.attr('string', {key: 'css_name'}),
    storageID: DS.attr('number', {defaultValue: 0, key: 'storageID'}),

});

// ==========================================================================
// Test Application
// ==========================================================================


App.store.createRecord(App.StyleData, { css_name: 'name' });
App.store.commit()   
//console: createRecord:  App.StyleData, model

App.store.find(App.StyleData, 0)   
//console: find: App.StyleData, 0

App.store.updateRecord(App.StyleData, { css_name: 'new name' });  
//console: Uncaught TypeError: Object <DS.Store:ember195> has no method 'updateRecord'
```

Pretty much at the end of my wits here since I can't figure out what is going on underneath the hood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was the same position at one point, since the conceptual difference between the store's methods (`createRecord`, `deleteRecord`, `find`, etc.) and the adapter's methods doesn't seem to really be made clear in the available documentation.

As for `updateRecord`, the store doesn't have one. To update, you merely `.set` the values in the `Model` and run `App.store.commit()`. This will call the adapter's `updateRecord`.

Comment: Ok everything makes a lot more sense now. The joys of Ember Data